# How can i get api data with params [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, api

here is my controller code:

```
public function tournaments() {
        $data = 0;
        $response = Http::withHeaders(
            [
                'x-rapidapi-host'=> 'uxxxx',
                'x-rapidapi-key'=> 'asdfasdfas',
            ]
    )->get('https://unibet.p.rapidapi.com/competitions-by-sport/football');
return $response;
}
```

and response message received: `{"message":"Missing required parameters"}`

How can i add parameters to these code? for exmpl: `params: {sport: 'football'},`

And maybe someone could share a tutorial video on how to work with the API LARAVEL?

Comment: You shouldn't post your api key on Stack overflow, you should mask it

Comment: you should get a new key now, the edit history for this post is publicly visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about query parameters, that's what you're looking for: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#get-request-query-parameters

> When making GET requests, you may either append a query string to the
> URL directly or pass an array of key / value pairs as the second
> argument to the get method

Here's an example of what it would look like:

```
public function tournaments() {
    $data = 0;
    $response = Http::withHeaders(
        [
            'x-rapidapi-host'=> 'uxxxx',
            'x-rapidapi-key'=> 'asdfasdfas',
        ]
    )->get('https://unibet.p.rapidapi.com/competitions-by-sport', [
        'sport' => 'football'
    ]);
    return $response;
}
```